# XPath: find <dd> sibling elements between two <dt> elements which are also siblings

Tags: javascript, html, xpath, web-scraping

I have this structure:

```
<dl>
  <!-- preceded by a variable amount of <dt> and <dd> nodes -->
  <dt>Venues</dt>
  <dd>Madison Square Garden</dd>
  <dd>Wembley</dd>
  <!-- there could be more venues (in <dd>) here -->
  <!-- the following <dt> doesn't necessarily have to contain text "Event" - it can be something else, too -->
  <dt>Event</dt>
  <dd>Grand opening</dd>
  <dt>Series</dt>
  <dd>Golden Virginia 49</dd>
  <!-- a variable amount of <dt> and <dd> nodes continues -->
</dl>
```

I am trying to extract `Venues` in a browser context (i.e. Javascript):

- *Madison Square Garden*
- *Wembley*

How do I do this?

My closest attempt was:

`$x("//dt[text()='Venues']/following-sibling::dd")`

... but that gets me all the `<dd>` elements, whereas **I'm trying to get the `<dd>` elements between two `<dt>` elements in a scenario where the amount of `<dt>` and `<dd>` elements is variable**, which I believe, and I may be wrong, rules out the use of `count()`.

Comment: You mention that "<!-- the following <dt> doesn't necessarily have to have text()='Event' -->
  <dt>Event</dt>"; is that`<dt>` otherwise empty or does it have some other text?

Comment: What I wanted to say was that the `<dt>` following the `<dd>` elements after `<dt>Venues</dt>` doesn't have to contain text "Event"

Answer (score 2):

So I believe to extract the `dd` tags between the various `dt` tags you're going to have to use a some slightly different xpaths making use of `following-sibling` as well as `preceding-sibling`.

To get `dd` tags containing the 'Venues' information you would use the following xpath:

`//dt[contains(text(), 'Venues')]/following-sibling::dt[contains(text(), 'Event')]/preceding-sibling::dd/text()`

This xpath first focuses on the `dt` tag containg the text 'Venues'. It then focuses on the following sibling `dt` tag containing the text 'Event'. And then looks for all the `dd` tags preceding that current path giving you:

- Madison Square Garden
- Wembley

However, you can't use this xpath to get the information for 'Event' by replacing the `dt` contains text to 'Event' and 'Series' in the way it was done in the first xpath. This gives the same issue you noted where you get more `dd` tags than you are wanting. You would now have to use this xpath:

`//dt[contains(text(), 'Event')]/following-sibling::dt[contains(text(), 'Series')]/preceding-sibling::dd[preceding-sibling::dt[contains(text(), 'Event')]]/text()`

Here the preceding-sibling `dd` tags of the 'Series' `dt` tag must have a preceding-sibling itself which is a `dt` tag containing the text 'Event'. This gives you:

- Grand opening

To get the `dd` tags under 'Series' (the last `dt` tag contained in the `dl` parent node, then you can make use of the xpath you originally tired).

Hope this helps. You were on the right path. Sometimes a lot of trial and error has to go in to finding the nodes you're trying to hit.

Comment: In fact, you could actually ignore the first xpath in the post and just make use of the second one. This should work for all dd tags that have a preceding and following dt tag. Its only the last dd tags that you would then use the original xpath you tried using

Answer (score 1):

This answer probably won't work for @TheOnin, but may be useful for others.  If you're using XPath in an environment that provides access to the `current()` function – for example in XSLT – then you can do something like the following, having first ensured the current node is the 'Venues' `<dt>`:

```
following-sibling::dd[preceding-sibling::dt[1]=current()]
```

This finds *all* following `<dd>` elements, and then restricts it to those whose closest previous `<dt>` element is the current element, which you arrange to be the 'Venues' `<dt>`.

An example of this in XSLT is:

```xml
<xsl:template name="find-dds">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::dd[preceding-sibling::dt[1]=current()]"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template ...>
  <xsl:call-templates select="//dt[contains(text(), 'Venues')]" name="find-dds"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Although @TheOnin doesn't say exactly which Javascript library they're using to provide the `$(...)` XPath query interface, I'm not aware of any which supports `current()` in this way.  Nevertheless, others might find it useful.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that each `<dl>` only has one `<dt>Venues</dt>` and only one other `<dt>` and that these two `<dt>`s appear within the `<dl>` in that order, the following xpath should get all the venue `<dd>`s regardless of how many there are:

```
//dl//dd[preceding-sibling::dt[.="Venues"]][not(preceding-sibling::dt[not(.="Venues")])]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work - I'm getting an empty resultset. A few things that weren't successfully communicated: (i) there are multiple `<dt>` within the `<dl>` (ii) order isn't guaranteed, but if it makes it easier, an `<dt>Foobar</dt>` is always before `<dt>Venus</dt>` (and there are `<dd>` in between) *but* not always _right_ before.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac Well, I can only work with what you post. If possible, try to edit the question with either the actual html or at least a representative sample.

Comment: I believe I have the representative sample - which part do you reckon isn't congruent with my description? Also, thanks.

Comment: @NinoŠkopac I can't really answer that. What I know is that, given the sample html in the question, the xpath expression in the answer outputs "MSG" and "Wembley". Since you get an empty resultset on your actual html, it means that the html in the question is not representative of the actual html.